# Using Walter Savitch Linked List Interface

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to learn data structures and I started with single linked list. I am first trying to just memorize and understand the code that Walter Savitch provided in Ch.13 of Absolute C++. I am having some trouble using the interface that the author designed for a single linked list. Specifically, I understand the code but I do not understand how to use the interface to create a single linked list in terms of the syntax needed.

Here is the interface:

```
#ifndef LinkedList_hpp
#define LinkedList_hpp

namespace LinkedList {

    template<class T>
    class Node {
    private:
        T data;
        Node<T> *link;
    public:
        Node(const T& theData, Node<T>* theLink) : data(theData), link(theLink) {}
        Node<T>* getLink() {return link;}
        const T getData() const {return data;}
        void setData(const T& theData) {data = theData;}
        void setLink(Node<T>* pointer) {link = pointer;}
    };

    template<class T>
    void headInsert(Node<T>*& head, const T& theData) {
        head = new Node<T>(theData, head);
    }

    template<class T>
    void insert(Node<T>* next, const T& theData) {
        next->setLink(new Node<T>(theData, next->getLink( )));
    }

    template<class T>
    void deleteNode(Node<T>* before) {
        Node<T>* discard;
        discard = before->getLink();
        before->setLink(discard->getLink( ));
        delete discard;
    }

    template<class T>
    void deleteFirstNode(Node<T>*& head) {
        Node<T>* discard;
        discard = head;
        head = head->getLink();
        delete discard;
    }

    template<class T>
    Node<T>* search(Node<T>* head, const T& target) {
        Node<T>* here = head;
        if(here == nullptr) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else {
            while(here->getData() != target && here->getLink() != nullptr)
                here = here->getLink();
            if(here->getData() == target)
                return here;
            else
                return nullptr;
        }
    }
}


#endif /* LinkedList_hpp */
```

Now I am trying to just use the interface to create a single linked list. But I am having some trouble. Here is how far I have gone.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"

using namespace LinkedList;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Node<int> test(2,nullptr);


    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me just show me what I need to write into the int main() body to create a single linked list and perhaps print its contents? Just for ease of simplicity I want to try to make a single linked list look like this:

[image]

Comment: The question is too broad. You're asking us to write code for you. You should ask a specific question about something you didn't understand. What is the "some trouble" you're having?

Comment: @Neo I re-edited the post. I am having trouble understanding the syntax I need to use the interface to create a single linked list.

Comment: Two ways I can think of to build that: start at 50 and go backwards calling `headInsert` or start at 10, and call `insert` on the last node inserted. Unfortunately `insert` doesn't return the note it created and inserted, so you'll have to do your own iteration to find it.

Comment: That interface is just horrendous.

Comment: @n.m. Not going to argue that. I think Savitch is trying to teach something. Perhaps it's don't write a linked list like this in C++

Comment: Anyway, back to an earlier, now-deleted comment. Draw your current list. Then draw what you want the list to look like after adding the first node.  Figure out how you are going to do that in code using the provided interface.  Put some thought into whether or not what you have in mind will make it easy to add a second node into the right spot. Code it, run it, test it. Then draw what you want the list to look like after step two. Figure out how you are going to do that in code. If you didn't put enough thought into step 1 you might find yourself throwing out what you've already written.

Comment: All of you have great suggestions. Although, it seems that this interface is bad in case of a linked list. If that is the case I won't bother trying to get the results I want.

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions on what linked list code I should work from that is not deemed "horrendous"?

Comment: @n.m. Just want to get your attention to the latter since you said this interface is horrendous.

Comment: Use std::list for a while, then implement a simplified version of it. Be wary of getter/setter pairs, they are utterly pointless 99% of the time and only expose data members with a slightly different access syntax. If you need to expose data members, just make them public. Users of a well designed list class should not see a Node anyway, it ought to be internal to the list implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how that interface could be accessed:

```
Node<int> node(20,nullptr);
Node<int> *head = &node;

insert(head, 30);

prnt(head);

std::cout << "Searching for 10..." << search(head, 10) << std::endl;

headInsert(head, 10);

std::cout << "Searching for 10..." << search(head, 10) << std::endl;

prnt(head);

deleteFirstNode(head);

prnt(head);

deleteNode(head);

prnt(head);
```

Included is `prnt` method, which traverses the current list from the head until it finds a `nullptr`, printing the data at each node and helps demonstrate what each method does. The method is as follows:

```
template<class T>
void prnt(Node<T>* head) {
    for (; head->getLink(); head=head->getLink()){
    std::cout << head->getData() << " -> ";
    }
    std::cout << head->getData() << std::endl;
}
```